# How to add functionality to buttons of each of the recyclerview items?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-button

I am writing an android code, wherein on clicking a button on the recyclerview,  it should direct it to some other activity. The program should redirect the control to different activities for each of the recyclerview items. I have successfully added buttons to the template of the activity, however, I am not able to understand how to add functionality to each of the buttons. I am enclosing herewith the the different files that I have included in the project. It would be very helpful if someone could guide me how to proceed from here.

> ProductPage1.java

```
package com.agnik.example.myapplication4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductPage1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_page1);

        ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}
```

> ExampleAdapter.java

```
package com.agnik.example.myapplication4;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;


    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;
        public Button mButton;

        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);


        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList)
    {

        mExampleList = exampleList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();

    }







}
```

> ExampleItem.java

```
    package com.agnik.example.myapplication4;

    public class ExampleItem {

        private int mImageResource;
        private String mText1;
        private String mText2;

        public ExampleItem(int imageResource, String text1, String text2) {
            mImageResource = imageResource;
            mText1 = text1;
            mText2 = text2;
        }

        public int getImageResource() {
            return mImageResource;
        }

        public String getText1() {
            return mText1;
        }

        public String getText2() {
            return mText2;
        }

    }
```

> activity_product_page1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductPage1">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#008080"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> example_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Line 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Line 2"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mybutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Purchase"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"  />


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

> activity_product_page1.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductPage1">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#008080"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwoUn.png)

EDIT:

As mentioned by Phil, I need to add setOnClickListener with the holder object.
However, I am not able to understand how should I transfer control from ProductPage1.class to SomeOtherActivity.class as I am writing the code on ExampleAdapter.java?

```
   holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 1:                 

                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_1.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_2.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_3.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_4.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_5.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_6.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_7.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, PageDemo1_3.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                }



            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this inside the onBindViewHolder method in ExampleAdapter.

As an example you could do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your code here
            }
    });

}
```

Inside the onBindViewHolder() method "the logic happens". There you can set up everything for each of the RecyclerView items.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I add functionality to each of the button items. I am not able to understand how to access each of the buttons present in the recyclerview.

Comment: The onBindViewHolder method gets called for every item that gets displayed. To check which item gets clicked you could use the "position" attribute. Just make it final and then you can use it inside the onClick() method.
Maybe first add this line inside the onClick() method:
Log.d("Your Tag", "clicked item with position: " + position);
Then you should see if it works properly.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. One thing that I would like to ask is that since I am writing the code in ExampleAdapter.class, and the application redirects the control from Productpage1.java to SomeOtherClass.java, so what name should I specify in the intent method?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(ProductPage1.class, SomeotherClass.class);
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an interface that is similar to the normal click listener, except it also has the position as a parameter.

```
public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

then you can declare in your adaper

```
private final RecyclerViewClickListener listener;
```

and you can create a setter in adapter

```
public void setListner(RecyclerViewClickListener listener){
this.listener=listener;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a callback Interface into the Adapter and pass an instance of the Interface from the Activity to the Adapter constructor. Call the method(s) of the interface when you click the different ViewGroup of the recyclerview items and there should be an implementation into the Activity. Your codes will look like this

Activity

```
    public class ProductPage1 extends AppCompatActivity implements ClickCallback {

        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_page1);

            ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mickeymouse, "Line1" , "Line2"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.donalduck, "Line3" , "Line4"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.popey, "Line5" , "Line6"));

            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);

            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

       @Override
       onItemClick(int position, View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
           case R.id.mImageView:
         //do your view click events here
            break;
           case R.id.mImageView2:
         //do your view click events here
           break;
         //so on
       }
 }
```

Adapter

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;


    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;
        public Button mButton;

        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,ClickCallback clickCallback) {
            super(itemView);
this.clickCallback=clickCallback;
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);


        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList)
    {

        mExampleList = exampleList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());

holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              clickCallback.onItemClick(position, holder.mImageView);
            //and same for other views
             }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();

    }


    public interface ClickCallback{
        void onItemClick(int position, View view);
         //here you can send the object of the list at the position if you require 
         //that in activity

    }
}
```

Hope you got the answer. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This code shows an Dialog on each item clicked

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, null);
        final ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
        dialoge = new Dialog(parent.getContext());
        dialoge.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialoge.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        viewHolder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setDialog(dialoge, viewHolder);
                dialoge.show();
            }

        });

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

and in the methode setDialog() you get the current item position by using

```
final RecyclerItem currentItem = itemList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

But i think the best practice is to consider using an inerface and here is a good tutorial to follow [tutorialRecyclerItemOnClickListenerInterface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0)

I hope this helps you

> EDIT : Start an activity from the onClickListnere :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(parent.getContext(),yourActivityName.class);
                myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
```